# Validation on numbers with jquery.bassistance validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I used the jquery.bassistance validation plugin. For validation on my fields. Now i want validation on my arrival text box. I want that he validate on this box. The only characters that you used in this checkbox are numbers and the :.

How can i make that. I used now this code:

```
$(".validate").validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            number: {
                required:true,
                minlength:3,
                phoneAus:true   
            },
            math: {
                equal: 11
            },
            agree: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            email: "Vul een geldig email adres in",
            agree: "Je moet nog akkoord gaan met voorwaarden"
        },
        errorLabelContainer: $("form .error-messages")
    });
```

But the number validation. Validate on numbers. How can i fix that the number validation. Accept the : sign.

Thanks

Comment: could you show us the html form!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a custom regex rule, here is a starting point, you will need to update the regex to your specific requirements:

```
$(function ()
{
    $.validator.addMethod("customRegex", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9\:]+$/i.test(value);
    }, "must contain only numbers, or a colon.");

    $(".validate").validate({
        rules: {
            "fieldId": {
                required: true,
                customRegex: true,
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "fieldId": {
                required: "You must enter a xyz",
                customRegex: "format not valid"
            }
        }
    });
});
```